# how to get the union of hashes in ruby for this json structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Below is json I translated from ruby hash for ease of representation for this question using `hash.to_json`. Notice how the key `range` is being repeated since the values in the nested doc are different. How do I merge the ranges so that for the `weight` key both `"gt": 2232, "lt": 4444` fall under the one hash key weight inside range. Is there some union or collapse method in ruby to sort of "compactify" hashes?

```
{
    "must": [
        {
            "match": {
                "status_type": "good"
            }
        },
        {
            "range": {
                "created_date": {
                    "lte": 43252
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "range": {
                "created_date": {
                    "gt": "42323"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "range": {
                "created_date": {
                    "gte": 523432
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "range": {
                "weight": {
                    "gt": 2232
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "range": {
                "weight": {
                    "lt": 4444
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "should": [
        {
            "match": {
                "product_age": "old"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Want to change the above to this:

```
{
    "must": [
        {
            "range": {
                "created_date": {
                    "gte": 523432,
                    "gt": "42323"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "range": {
                "weight": {
                    "gt": 2232,
                    "lt": 4444
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "should": [
        {
            "match": {
                "product_age": "old"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a built in way to handle something like this, but you could write a method that does something like this:

```
def collapse(array, key)
  # Get only the hashes with :range
  to_collapse = array.select { |elem| elem.has_key? key }

  uncollapsed = array - to_collapse

  # Get the hashes that :range points to
  to_collapse = to_collapse.map { |elem| elem.values }.flatten

  collapsed = {}

  # Iterate through each range hash and their subsequent subhashes.
  # Collapse the values into the collapsed hash as necessary
  to_collapse.each do |elem|
    elem.each do |k, v|
      collapsed[k] = {} unless collapsed.has_key? k
      v.each do |inner_key, inner_val|
        collapsed[k][inner_key] = inner_val
      end
    end
  end
  [uncollapsed, collapsed].flatten
end

hash[:must] = collapse hash[:must], :range
```

Note that this is a specific solution that's mainly applicable to the presented problem. It only works for the hash/array depths specified here. You could probably write a recursive solution that could potentially work at any level of depth with a bit more work.